# Â is appearing before the registration marks ® in my XML

Tags: xml, xslt

We have an excel that runs a look up and then exports to XML. The systems downstream are having issue due to the registration marks `®` are actually coming up as an `Â®`. I have no idea where the `Â` is coming from and I am only able to see it using a software called WinMerge.  I do not see the character in Excel, XMLSpy, Notepad…..

I tried running XSLT to replace any `®` to `&#174;` and `&#xae;` but that just created output that was exactly the same. I even replacing the letter ‘h’ before the registration mark and the registration mark to `h&#xae;` thinking that would remove it but it did not. I even tried creating an XSLT that would convert any `Â` to a blank space but it would not run. I need to provide the XML as UTF-8 so it can be processed downstream. Any suggestions?

The XML starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: It is typically something that happens when the file is encoded with utf-8, but the editor loads it with another (for example ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252). You should check that WinMerge loads the file with the correct encodng.

Comment: @potame Thanks. So are you implying that potentially WinMerge is looking at the XML, with is encoded at UTF-8, through ISO-8859-1 encoding and is showing the character, Â, that might not even actual be there? I apologize if I am totally off.

Comment: @potame Seems it could be the case. This is from the WinMerge manual, "Also, WinMergeU.exe correctly handles UTF-8 files, unlike WinMerge.exe". We are not using the 'U' version.

Comment: I think that WinMerge - like most text editors - doesn't look at the `encoding="..."` and tries to open the file with a defined encoding (or guessing it, for example with the help,of a byte-order-mark at the beginning of the file). However, you can face such an issue with parsers if ever you specify an encoding in the xml declaration (e.g. `<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, but physically save the file with a different encoding (e.g. "utf-8").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accented 'A' happens when you get your encoding wrong. The UTF-8 encoding for nbsp (in hex) is [C2][A0]. C2 in UTF-16 or Windows is Â, So, if you output `&nbsp;` in UTF-8, but don't tell whatever's loading it in Windows that it's UTF-8, you'll see the Â character. The exact same thing happens with a few characters around that code, including the registration mark.

Best suggestion would be to add

```
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
```

(I think- haven't tested that at this point).

Comment: Thanks you for the background information. I cannot change the data I am receiving from the excel spreadsheet so I am trying to figure out how to correct it before the data is passed downstream if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Good idea. I am testing a file and checking with the guys downstream to make sure it does not create issues for them.